# tabs disappear when starting new activity from tab content

Tags: android

I have five tabs in my application.One tabs contain several activity.That is i have set content(one activity) for that tab and later from the content(activity) calling another acivityforresult().But my tabs get disappear as soon as new activity started.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are looking for a concept called **ActivityGroup**.

I have listed a few sites which will be helpful in learning things and get started with it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html

http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/

Comment: thanks for quick response. yes I am already using this concept but i want to call activityforresult() so that some result can be obtained from called acivity.